# Fragment on Screen Rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have added a viewpager to an activity which contains two page.

In onCreate of activity I add fragments to a fragmentAdapter:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ......

    FragmentAdapter fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter
    (
        getSupportFragmentManager(),
        new Fragment[]{FragmentGame.builder(id), FragmentComments.builder(id)},
        new String[]{getString(R.string.gameInfo), getString(R.string.comments)}
    );

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);

public static FragmentGame builder(long id)
{
    FragmentGame fragmentGame = new FragmentGame();

    // fragmentGame.id = id;

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putLong(Constants.EXTRA_ID, id);
    fragmentGame.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragmentGame;
}
```

First time that activity is created the **onCreateView** of fragment is called as it's expected.

The strange behaviour is when the screen is rotated for the first time the **onCreateView** of fragment is called twice but the second call only has the correct **id** and for the first call **id** is 0.

On second screen rotation, **onCreateView** is called three times and again only the last one has id.

By more screen rotation, **onCreateView** calls increase.

I found some related question about fragment and screen rotation but I can't figure out why this happens and how to do it the right way.

----- UPDATE ------

The ID problem is solved as I replaced bundle with direct value setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every time you rotate your device you are creating a new fragment and adding it to the FragmentManager.

All of your previously created fragments are still in the FragmentManager therefore the count increases by one each time.

If you wish to retain a value in your fragment, you need to store it in the arguments otherwise any values it contains would be lost when the system re-creates the fragment.

```
public static FragmentGame builder(long id) {
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putInt("id", id);
 fragmentGame f = new fragmentGame();
 f.setArguments(args);
}
```

Rather than creating a new fragment, I suspect you really want to retrieve your previously created one when you rotate the device. use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` or `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag()` to do this.

Edit: Extra code

```
    // Add fragment to the manager
    FragmentTransaction trans=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    trans.add(f,"myTag");
    trans.commit();

    // retrieve the fragment
    Fragment f= getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myTag");
```

Just attempt to retrieve the fragment, if the value is null, create a new fragment and add it to the manager otherwise use the retrieved one.

Comment: I replaced the direct value setting with arguments in my question. I would prefer to retrieve old fragment instead of creating new one. Would you please add some codes about retrieving old fragments. I think findFragmentById is not applicable in viewPager. How can I use findFragmentByTag and how to add tag to fragments?

Comment: The fragment isn't added to fragmentManager automatically? why do we pass FragmentManager to FragmentPagerAdapter? Is there any way to totally destroy old fragments on screen rotation?

Comment: Some components or adapters may add it for you but generally no. You can remove old fragments by calling the remove method of the fragmentTransaction but usually you would use the fragment you have rather than create a new one

Comment: I wonder if configuration changes are the only situations that this happens? I mean for example pausing or exiting app doesn't lead to this? If this is the only situation then I prefer to stop it by fixing the screen rotation.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to reload your fragment on orientation change, write following for the activity in which you are loading the fragment in manifest file.

```
<activity
            android:name="your activity name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" // add this to your activity
            android:label="@string/app_name">
 </activity>
```

Comment: I know this, but is this the only situation that this happens?

Comment: There is an another way by saving your object onSaveInstanceState & retrieving on onRestoreInstanceState() methods. You have to implement parcelable on your objects for this.

Comment: This may work but it is a "frowned upon" approach as you are disabling the normal resource management and fragment lifecycle and it pains me that so many people have upvoted this because they are now likely causing other issues for themselves. Better to do it properly in the first place instead of fudging it like this. e.g if you have separate layouts for landscape, these will never be loaded when using this method.