# Is there any reason using FragmentTransaction.replace instead of FragmentTransaction.add during first time commit?

Tags: android

When I look back at the old code of a projects, I realize the entire project is using `FragmentTransaction.replace` instead of `FragmentTransaction.add`.

```
public class UpgradePremiumFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            UpgradePremiumFragment upgradePremiumFragment = UpgradePremiumFragment.newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, upgradePremiumFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        } else {
        }
    }
```

I was wondering, is there any reason for using `replace` instead of `add` in the above case? As `savedInstanceState` is null, so there shouldn't be an old fragment for replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Replace prevents you having multiple identical fragments.

If you use Add the fragment is simply added to the FragmentManager. Replace will remove any other fragments that have the same id (occupy the same container) before adding.

If you are 100% certain that there is no previous fragment then you can safely use "Add".

From the docs:

> public abstract FragmentTransaction replace (int containerViewId,
>   Fragment fragment, String tag)
>
> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is
>   essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently
>   added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then
>   add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

Comment: But as you can see, the code is during `onCreate` state and `savedInstanceState` is null. So, is it possible that there is old fragment there?

Comment: There could be fragments held in the FragmentManager. They are not necessarily destroyed upon (for instance) a device rotation like an activity would be. It depends on your exact use case whether using one has a benefit over using the other.

Comment: This question may explain it a little more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219458/fragment-on-screen-rotation/19219755#19219755